# Accessing external storage on Nucleo

Tags: embedded, stm32, stm32f4, nucleo

There is 1.6 MB of external storage shows when we connect Nucleo to PC. Can we access that storage to save or read files from it from application i.e. in code? I haven't found any particular solution anywhere so asking here.

Comment: What specific Nucleo board do you have?   The resources on your board will be described in the data sheet.  Your board however does not have 1.6Mb of "_external storage_".  I am sure of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except the "major" MCU for application, there is another MCU on the Nucleo board works as a programmer (ST-Link). This auxiliary MCU is connected to the application MCU with an UART for virtual com port, and a SWD for programming. That 1.6 MB of external storage you see on PC is emulated by this programmer MCU, and the firmware in this MCU has no simple way to be modified (suppose you still need it to act as a functional programmer and VCP). So the answer to your question is **no simple way to do that**, unless you are willing to sacrifice the programmer functionality of the auxiliary MCU and write a protocol to access the emulated storage on that MCU.

Answer (score 0):

The mass storage device presented is not real, it is presented by the Nucleo bootloader/debugger interface chip as a simple drag-and-drop means of programming without additional software on the host PC.  It is a means of programming the *on-chip* flash of the STM32 and is *not external storage*.